# Retrieving image uploaded from ASP.NET page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, forms, upload

I've got an ASP.NET upload form on one page, where the user can upload an image. heres the code for that one:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>

<html>

<head>

<script language="VB" runat="server">

Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

       If imageupload1.HasFile Then
        imageupload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(".") + "/uploadedimages/" & imageupload1.FileName)
           Label1.Text = "Received " & imageupload1.FileName & " Content Type " & imageupload1.PostedFile.ContentType & " Length " & imageupload1.PostedFile.ContentLength
       Else
           Label1.Text = "No uploaded file"
       End If

end sub

</script>

</head>

<body>

<form id="imguplad" runat=server>

<asp:FileUpLoad id="imageupload1" AlternateText="You cannot upload files" runat="server" />
<asp:Button id="Button1" Text="Upload" OnClick="Button1_Click" runat="server" />
<asp:Label id="Label1" runat="server" />
<input type="button" value="Click here when image is uploaded"
onClick="location.href='imageloadtest.aspx';">
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Then I am trying to retrieve it on another page, using the following code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>
...blah
<body>

<img id="image" src="Server.MapPath(".")+"/uploadedimages/"+Request.Form["imageupload1.FileName"]";">

</body>
...blah
```

Can't seem to get it to show up? I must have some path slightly wrong.

EDIT: By the way, the image uploads perfectly, it just won't show up on the next page.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
<img id="image" src="<%=Server.MapPath("~")%>/uploadedimages/<%=Request.Form["imageupload1.FileName"]%>">
```

You also may have to set manually the image name in session because you won't have access to `imageupload1.FileName` in another page, where the control `imageupload1` doesn't exist.

So in your click event add `Session["ImagePath"] = imageupload1.FileName`
And the `img` tag replace `Request.Form["imageupload1.FileName"]` by `Session["ImagePath"]`

Comment: no luck with that. im using a "." throughout the whole project, so that should be correct anyway? thanks

Comment: hum sorry, I changed my mind few seconds after... I think there is a mismatch with how the code should be used in aspx page... So I updated the full `img` tag.

Comment: that doesn't seem to want to work either, now it just doesnt display anything (even the broken picture icon). thanks

Comment: Huuum probably because the imageupload1 doesn't exist on the page. Try with the change I added : setting the filename in session.

Comment: And you should view the source of the page to check what path is written in the `img` tag. It may help to understand what is wrong.

Comment: where abouts in the click event would the Session["ImagePath"] = imageupload1.FileName go? thanks

Comment: Almost anywhere, but after `imageupload1.SaveAs(..)` would probably be the best place